# How can I make visual keyboard appear above my UIToolBar? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITextView at the middle of a View, a UIToolBar at the bottom of a View. I want a visual keyboard to appear above a UIToolBar when I touch on UITextView. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The position of the keyboard isn't under the control of the application. (Oh, you could muck around in the UIApplication's UIWindow list to find the keyboard window and move it, but then Apple wouldn't accept your app.)

Comment: Can i make a "Dismiss" key and add it to visual keyboard?

Comment: Yes- you make a thin strip UIView, listen for the keyboard{Will,Did}{Show,Hide} notifications, (and rotation callbacks) animate your view so it stays just above the keyboard, and put your UIButton on that view. I'm under the impression that that's what UIWebView does for its Done button.